# How to return array of promises inside map in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function handler(){
    const results = [].map((item) => {
      a();
      b();
    })
    Promise.allSettled(results);
  }

  function a() {
    // returns promise
  }
  function b() {
    // returns promise
  }
}
```

How to modify the above code so that I can pass array of promises to `promise.allSettled(results)`

I tried this but not sure if this is correct way?

```
function handler() {
    const results = [].map((item) => {
      const out1 = a();
      const out2 = b();
      return [...out1, ...out2];
    })
    Promise.allSettled(results);
}
```

Comment: you want flatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

const b = a.flatMap(v => [Promise.resolve(a), Promise.reject(a)])

Promise.allSettled(b).then(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```js
function handler() {
    const results = [].map((item) => {
      const out1 = a();
      const out2 = b();
      return [...out1, ...out2];
    })
    Promise.allSettled(results.flat());
}
```